# How can I find out the command line options for git-bash.exe?

Tags: windows, command-line, git-bash

Apparently my google-fu sucks...

I know these from other StackExchange posts:

```
--cd-to-home    # Change directory to home
--cd=<path>     # Change directory to <path>
-i              # ?
-c              # Run command, but --command doesn't work/exist
```

Where can I find a complete list of options for git-bash.exe (the therminal emulator)? I found them for mintty [[1](https://mintty.github.io/mintty.1.html)], but they don't seem to be the correct ones for git-bash.exe...

---

**Update:**

So `git-bash.exe` just seems to be a simple wrapper that first parses the `--cd...` options and then runs

```
usr\bin\mintty.exe --icon git-bash.exe,0 --exec "/usr/bin/bash" --login -i <other arguments>
```

or similar. That's why only `--cd..` and bash options are parsed correctly and not mintty.

If you want to use other options from mintty, you should use a similar command instead of trying to do it with *git-bash.exe*. E.g.:

```
usr\bin\mintty.exe --icon git-bash.exe,0 --window full --exec "/usr/bin/bash" --login -i -c "echo 'Hello World!'; read"
```

Comment: Did you tried to start with `help`? If it works like git under linux from command-line you can ask `git --help -a` to have the full list of commands.

Comment: [so] duplicate: [gitbash command quick reference](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6498045)

Comment: git-bash.exe is the terminal emulator (based on mintty) which has collection of standard commands like `ls` or `git` (based on msys). I know how to get the options for those commands, I'm looking for the options for the terminal emulator. I have also tried `git-bash.exe --help` and `git-bash.exe /?`, both don't show anything.

Comment: @DavidPostill not a dupe -- this asks for *command-line options* to the shell invocation command

Comment: It may be worth moving your edit to an answer and mark that as the answer.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I also wondered on how to get command line options and Google search brought up this thread.

I found that the options are documented within git.

Call:

```
git help git-bash
```

and it will open up a git-bash manual page in your browser explaining all the options

Comment: Wow thanks, this is what I meant. I never thought about looking for the tool documentation within the git documentation itself...

Answer (score 29):

I found this commit from 2015 that introduced new command line options:
https://github.com/git/git/commit/ac6b03cb4197311b055dc5f46ab10bf37c591ae6

Here is the list from the commit description:

```
--command=<command-line>::
    Executes `<command-line>` instead of the embedded string resource

--[no-]minimal-search-path::
    Ensures that only `/cmd/` is added to the `PATH` instead of
    `/mingw??/bin` and `/usr/bin/`, or not

--[no-]needs-console::
    Ensures that there is a Win32 console associated with the spawned
    process, or not

--[no-]hide::
    Hides the console window, or not
```

You can read the full information in the URL above.

Answer (score 25):

Correct there isn't a list of command line options help for git-bash.exe. I spend some time looking for them myself and there isn't any proper documentation on it. It appears to be a wrapper for bin/sh.exe. If you really need to do more then I recommend looking at the help info for sh.exe instead.

Comment: Ah yes, this seems accurate for the options like `-c`, `-i`, `--login` etc. Here's the [online man page](http://linux.die.net/man/1/sh). I mainly was wondering what the `-i` option does. `--cd-to-home` and `--cd` aren't `sh` commands though (neither `mintty`), so I guess they were added for convenience and wonder if there are more...
PS: There's also *C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin\mintty.exe*

Comment: same for git-cmd.exe no doc and the args ConEmu passes, --no-cd and --command, have nothing to do with cmd.exe

Answer (score 4):

Here is the command line you found when you start `git-bash.exe` (on 2.8.1)

```
usr\bin\mintty.exe -o AppID=GitForWindows.Bash -o RelaunchCommand="C:\Git\git-bash.exe" -o RelaunchDisplayName="Git Bash" -i /mingw32/share/git/git-for-windows.ico /usr/bin/bash --login -i
```